# flex Dictionary dataProvider?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript

I have a Dictionary that I'd like to bind as the dataProvider for an mx:ComboBox.  e.g., when I do this:

```
       mydict[somenewkey]= somenewval;
```

I'd like the combobox to update its contents.

The problem is that Dictionary doesn't seem to be Bindable.  If I were using an Array, I'd use ArrayCollection.  But there doesn't seem to be a corresponding DictionaryCollection or HashCollection.  What to do?

Comment: In what format do you expect a ComboBox to display the data in your Dictionary? I understand that you want key-value pairs, but that's not what combo box expects. It wants something list-like that is either an ICollectionView or something can be converted to one like Array or XMLList.

Maybe a better question to ask is, why do you need key-value pairs? Do you happen to need it elsewhere, and maybe you're hoping to optimize by keeping all the data in one place? Or is it vitally important for some reason that ComboBox references the pairs somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Dictionary is not the appropriate object for a dataProvider of a list based class.

I suspect your display problems have nothing to do with data binding, but rather other issues, such as a dictionary does not have a length property.

I suspect the ComboBox will treat your dictionary as a single object, not as a collection of multiple objects.

Comment: What would be an appropriate object to use?

Comment: I strongly recommend using a collection class, although you can also use Arrays, XMLList, or straight XML.

Comment: The problem is that those collections don't have key=>value semantics.

Comment: Very true.  Why do you need that?  
I guess, in theory, you could extend the ComboBox / List Class to accept a Dictionary as the dataProvider; but I'd hope you'd have a strong user case for doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an ObjectProxy:

http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flex/3/langref/mx/utils/ObjectProxy.html

Answer (score 0):

Isn't what you're looking for just a combination of the setItemAt and getItemIndex methods of the ArrayCollection?

```
_myAC.setItemAt( somenewval, _myAC.getItemIndex( somenewkey ) );
```